# Apple game question

Tags: intuition, game-theory

Player A and Player B play a game. On the middle of the table there is a pot full of $N$ apples of different weights. Player A starts first and chooses an apple and starts eating it. Losing no time Player B does the same. When a player eats a whole apple, without losing time repeat the same procedure. In case both players have eaten their apple at the same time, Player A still has the advantage of choosing first. Note that both players eat with the same speed.

What apple should Player A choose at first to ensure that with right tactics he'll eat as much grams of apples as possible if Player B plays optimally?

---

I wasn't able to achieve much progress. I thought that if Player A chose the lightest apple  then he'll choose first in the "second round", but it's not the solution when we have 4 apples that  weigh: $300, 400, 500$ and $600$ grams. But also choosing the biggest apple isn't a solution. Example: Apples with $300, 400, 500$ grams, because choosing the smallest apple is the optimal solution.

Any help?

Comment: Are apple's weights given?

Comment: @the_candyman No. Actually this is programming contest problem, but my problem isn't with the code it's about the intuition/ideal tactics for this problem.

Comment: I conjecture that playing to merely _win_ (irrespective of _by how much_) should be sufficient. This should make things considerably easier.

Comment: If the problem is from a programming contest, then it's quite possible that the solution is very complicated and hard to describe theoretically (this tends to make for nice dynamic programming problems).

Comment: @GregMartin The question says, that there's always be only one answer. TO put that in other words if you don't choose the "winning apple" first then player B can win no matter what apple you choose later.

Comment: I believe that there's only one answer. That's not however inconsistent with my hunch about the solution.

Comment: Obviously, the optimal solution depends on the apple's weights. So we must at least assume that we have a function $w : N \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ representing those weights.

Comment: I think it will not always be the case that if you do not choose the winning apple that B automatically wins. Or rather, there is not always a "the" winning apple. For example {10,3,9} has a choice of two winning apples {3,9} and one loosing apple {10}.